# Getting random time when i add minutes to it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = new Date($("#dandt").val());
  var h = addZero(dt.getHours());
  var m = addZero(dt.getMinutes());
  $("#finalTime").val(h + ":" + m);


  function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
  }

  $('#checkcolore').on('change', function() {
    var time = $("#finalTime").val();
    var tempop = $("#tempcheckcolore").val();

    if (this.checked) {
      var dt = new Date(1900, 0, 1, time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1]);
      dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + tempop);
      $('#finalTime').val(addZero(dt.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(dt.getMinutes()));
    } else {
      var dt = new Date(1900, 0, 1, time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1]);
      dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() - tempop);
      $('#finalTime').val(addZero(dt.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(dt.getMinutes()));
    }
  });
  $('#TaglioCapelli').on('change', function() {
    var time = $("#finalTime").val();
    var tempoa = $("#tempTaglioCapelli").val();
    if (this.checked) {
      var dt = new Date(1900, 0, 1, time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1]);
      dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + tempoa);
      $('#finalTime').val(addZero(dt.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(dt.getMinutes()));
    } else {
      var dt = new Date(1900, 0, 1, time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1]);
      dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() - tempoa);
      $('#finalTime').val(addZero(dt.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(dt.getMinutes()));
    }
  });




});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <title>Booking - Book now</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="dandt" class="sr-only">Orario selezionato</label>
    <input type="text" name="dandt" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="dandt" value="2020/06/21 08:30">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="TaglioCapelli" id="TaglioCapelli">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="TaglioCapelli">
                       Taglio Capelli
                      </label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly value="30" name="tempTaglioCapelli" id="tempTaglioCapelli">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="tempTaglioCapelli">
                        Tempo in minuti
                       </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkcolore" id="checkcolore">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkcolore">
                        Colore Capelli
                      </label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly name="tempcheckcolore" value="40" id="tempcheckcolore">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="finalTime">Tempo finale stimato</label>
    <input type="text" name="finalTime" class="form-control" readonly id="finalTime" placeholder="">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

hello i'am getting random time when i try to add 30 or 40 minute to it :
so i have added snippet , it does the same thing in the snipset also, thanks again for any help.
if you can provide bette code ill accept it , i don't know what else to say.
Normaly the error occurs when both checkbox are selected.

[Look this to understand better what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1lGM.gif)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty updated

Comment: Great, suggested an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function addZero(i) {
    return (i < 10 ? "0" + i : i);
  }

  function addMinutes(d, m) {
    return new Date(d.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
  }

  function subMinutes(d, m) {
    return new Date(d.getTime() - (m * 60 * 1000));
  }

  Date.prototype.getTimeStamp = function() {
    var h = this.getHours();
    var m = this.getMinutes();
    return addZero(h) + ":" + addZero(m);
  }

  var dt = new Date($("#dandt").data("iso"));
  $("#finalTime").val(dt.getTimeStamp());

  $('#checkcolore').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      dt = addMinutes(dt, parseInt($("#tempcheckcolore").val()));
      $('#finalTime').val(dt.getTimeStamp());
    } else {
      dt = subMinutes(dt, parseInt($("#tempcheckcolore").val()));
      $('#finalTime').val(dt.getTimeStamp());
    }
  });
  $('#TaglioCapelli').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      dt = addMinutes(dt, parseInt($("#tempTaglioCapelli").val()));
      $('#finalTime').val(dt.getTimeStamp());
    } else {
      dt = subMinutes(dt, parseInt($("#tempTaglioCapelli").val()));
      $('#finalTime').val(dt.getTimeStamp());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group mb-2">
  <label for="dandt" class="sr-only">Orario selezionato</label>
  <input type="text" name="dandt" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="dandt" value="2020/06/21 08:30" data-iso="2020-06-21T08:30:00" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="TaglioCapelli" id="TaglioCapelli">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="TaglioCapelli">Taglio Capelli</label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly value="30" name="tempTaglioCapelli" id="tempTaglioCapelli">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="tempTaglioCapelli">Tempo in minuti</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkcolore" id="checkcolore">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkcolore">Colore Capelli</label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly name="tempcheckcolore" value="40" id="tempcheckcolore">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="finalTime">Tempo finale stimato</label>
  <input type="text" name="finalTime" class="form-control" readonly id="finalTime" placeholder="">
</div>
```

You will want to make functions to help you Add or Subtract minutes from a Date Object. The most precise method is to use Milliseconds, so we do some basic math and return a new Date Object.

I also added a function to extend the Date Object so that it's easier to print out Time (`08:30`).

Please review: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

> **dateString**
>
> A string value representing a date, specified in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method. (These formats are IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps, and also strings in a version of ISO8601.)

This is why I added a `data-iso` attribute to your `dandt` element. It's more easily ready by Date constructor. Since it's not as "pretty" it's not as used in Value.

Answer (score 0):

`setMinutes()` changes only the minutes portion of a Date object.

The reliable way to add or subtract time is by adding or subtracting milliseconds from the Date.

```js
var dt = new Date(1900,0,1,time.split(":")[0],time.split(":")[1]);
var starttime = dt.getTime(); // time in milliseconds
var changetime = tempop * 60 * 1000; // time to add/subtract in milliseconds
dt.setTime(starttime + changetime);
```

The following snippet resolves the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateTime = $("#dandt").val();
  var [date, time] = dateTime.split(' ');
  var [year, month, day] = date.split('/');
  var [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
  var dt = new Date(1900, 0, 1, hours, minutes);
  console.log('ready dt:', dt);
  $("#finalTime").val(hours + ":" + minutes);

  function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
  }

  function updateTime(changeMinutes, add) {
    let time = $("#finalTime").val();
    let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
    let addOrSubtract = add ? 1 : -1;
    let date = new Date(1900, 0, 1, hours, minutes);
    // console.log(`updateTime date:`, date);
    let currTime = date.getTime();
    date.setTime(currTime + (addOrSubtract * changeMinutes * 60 * 1000));
    // console.log(`updateTime new date:`, date);
    $('#finalTime').val(addZero(date.getHours()) + ":" +
      addZero(date.getMinutes()));
  }

  $('#checkcolore').on('change', function() {
    var tempop = $("#tempcheckcolore").val();
    updateTime(tempop, this.checked);
  });

  $('#TaglioCapelli').on('change', function() {
    let tempoa = $("#tempTaglioCapelli").val();
    updateTime(tempoa, this.checked);
  });




});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="dandt" class="sr-only">Orario selezionato</label>
    <input type="text" name="dandt" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="dandt" value="2020/06/21 08:30">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="TaglioCapelli" id="TaglioCapelli">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="TaglioCapelli">
                       Taglio Capelli
                      </label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly value="30" name="tempTaglioCapelli" id="tempTaglioCapelli">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="tempTaglioCapelli">
                        Tempo in minuti
                       </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkcolore" id="checkcolore">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkcolore">
                        Colore Capelli
                      </label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly name="tempcheckcolore" value="40" id="tempcheckcolore">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="finalTime">Tempo finale stimato</label>
    <input type="text" name="finalTime" class="form-control" readonly id="finalTime" placeholder="">
  </div>
```

Comment: in this way it gets worse